# WSO2 API Manager - Analytics Clustering

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

We have implemented Api-Manager Clustering and when we try to hit the api with large data some events are not captured by analytics

So we want to implement clustering for analytics - since there is no document available for apimanager - analytics clustering we have followed https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+Data+Analytics+Server+3.1.0.

We have implemented the Spark Deployment pattern - 2 node spark clustering but everytime in one node we are getting out of memory error

since the above one is not working we are planning to do the https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Fully+Distributed+High+Availability+Deployment+-+DAS+3.1.0 but it doesn't answer few question

1. How do they communicate each other - I mean some where we need to mention In reciver that Analyzer stays in some ip
2. And do the gateway need to point to reciever ?

Can Anyone help us

Thanks